# Restful Service C# Error on Console when deleting from List

Tags: c#, rest

I have a simple restful service that looks like this.

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            UriTemplate = "cars/{id}")]
        Car DeleteCar(string id);

    public class CarService : ICarService
    {
        private static List<Car> cList = new List<Car>()
        {
            new Car("VW","Polo",2010,200000,"VWP123"),
            new Car("Volvo","V70",2010,280000,"VOL123"),
            new Car("BMW","Z4",2014,400000,"BMW123")
        }; 

        public Car DeleteCar(string id)
        {
            Car c = GetCar(id);
            if (c == null) return null;
            cList.Remove(c);
            return c;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to consume it with a Console application, and it works, kind of. It deletes a car from the List as it should, but the console application crashes.

```
    carNo = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    Console.WriteLine(DeleteCar(carNo));

    private static Car DeleteCar(string frameNo)
    {
        Car car = DeleteCarAsync(frameNo).Result;
        return car;
    }

    private static async Task<Car> DeleteCarAsync(string frameNo)
    {
        string reqUri = baseUri + frameNo;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.DeleteAsync(reqUri);
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                throw new Exception("Car not found.");

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


            string str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Car car = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Car>(str);
            return car;

        }
    }
```

When running the code the console crashes with "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" on this  "Car car = DeleteCarAsync(frameNo).Result;" peticaler line. When I boot the Console back up, the list is printed and the Car I wanted to delete is gone.

Any insight will be appriciated..

**Edit:**
Heres the inner Exception you asked for:
[Inner Exceptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcGTT.jpg)

From what I understand from the error, its something about it not getting a json string return.

Comment: When you debug and look at the inner exceptions of the AggregateException, what are they?

Comment: in a RESTful service should your delete return anything?  Also see this

Comment: I think ideally it should only return [HttpStatusCode 204 No Content](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/)

Comment: Further testing shows that string str is returning an xmlns string and not a jason, this seems to be the root of the problem, but I dont understand why it's returning a xml when my GET that is quite simeler returns a JSON..

Heres the string that str is returning.
"<Car xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCFServiceWebRole1.Model\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><carFrameNo>BMW123</carFrameNo><carManufacture>BMW</carManufacture><carModel>Z4</carModel><carPrice>400000</carPrice><carYear>2014</carYear></Car>"